# Time series analysis applicability?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a sample data frame like this (date column format is `mm-dd-YYYY`):

```
date            count     grp
01-09-2009       54        1
01-09-2009       100       2
01-09-2009       546       3
01-10-2009       67        4
01-11-2009       80        5
01-11-2009       45        6
```

I want to convert this data frame into time series using `ts()`, but the problem is: the current data frame has multiple values for the same date. Can we apply time series in this case?

- Can I convert data frame into time series, and build a model (ARIMA) which can forecast count value on a daily basis?
- OR should I forecast count value based on grp, but in that case, I have to select only grp and count column of a data frame. So in that case, I have to skip date column, and daily forecast for count value is not possible?
- Suppose if I want to aggregate count value on per day basis. I tried with aggregate function, but there we have to specify date value, but I have a very large data set? Any other option available in r?

Can somebody, please, suggest if there is a better approach to follow? My assumption is that the time series forcast works only for bivariate data? Is this assumption right?

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end? Maybe aggregate the data per day? Have you read [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37519/building-a-time-series-that-includes-multiple-observations-for-each-date) post?

Comment: @lukeA aggregation is the only possible solution? yes, i want per day forecast for count value.

Comment: I dunno if this is the only possible solution. If you ask from a statistical perspective (instead of a programming point of view), http://stats.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask. Aggregation (e.g. summing counts per day) sounds like an easy solution to me at least...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are two aspects of your problem:

> i want to convert this data frame into time series using `ts()`, but the
>   problem is- current data frame having multiple values for the same
>   date. can we apply time series in this case?

If you are happy making use of the [**`xts`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/xts.pdf) package you could attempt:

```
dta2$date <- as.Date(dta2$date, "%d-%m-%Y")
dtaXTS <- xts::as.xts(dta2[,2:3], dta2$date)
```

which would result in:

```
>> head(dtaXTS)
           count grp
2009-09-01    54   1
2009-09-01   100   2
2009-09-01   546   3
2009-10-01    67   4
2009-11-01    80   5
2009-11-01    45   6
```

of the following classes:

```
>> class(dtaXTS)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

You could then use your time series object as univariate time series and refer to the selected variable or as a multivariate time series, example using [*`PerformanceAnalytics`*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/PerformanceAnalytics.pdf) packages:

```
PerformanceAnalytics::chart.TimeSeries(dtaXTS)
```

[image: multivariate time series]

## Side points

Concerning your second question:

> can somebody plz suggest me what is the better approach to follow, my
>   assumption is time series forcast is works only for bivariate data? is
>   this assumption also right?

IMHO, this is rather broad. I would suggest that you use created `xts` object and elaborate on the model you want to utilise and why, if it's a conceptual question about nature of time series analysis you may prefer to post your follow-up question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

---

*Data sourced via: `dta2 <- read.delim(pipe("pbpaste"), sep = "")` using the provided example.*

Answer (score 1):

Since daily forecasts are wanted we need to aggregate to daily.  Using `DF` from the Note at the end, read the first two columns of data into a zoo series `z` using `read.zoo` and argument `aggregate=sum`.  We could optionally convert that to a `"ts"` series (`tser <- as.ts(z)`) although this is unnecessary for many forecasting functions.  In particular, checking out the source code of `auto.arima` we see that it runs `x <- as.ts(x)` on its input before further processing.  Finally  run `auto.arima`, `forecast` or other forecasting function.

```
library(forecast)
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF[1:2], format = "%m-%d-%Y", aggregate = sum)

auto.arima(z)

forecast(z)
```

**Note:** `DF` is given reproducibly here:

```
Lines <- "date            count     grp
01-09-2009       54        1
01-09-2009       100       2
01-09-2009       546       3
01-10-2009       67        4
01-11-2009       80        5
01-11-2009       45        6"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

**Updated:** Revised after re-reading question.